# Why serial port read() return zero instead of data?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, tty

***GOAL:***

Configure a serial port /dev/ttyTHS1 on Linux 18 Jetson NANO with interrupter and non-standard baud rate for Sbus. The funny part is that it worked perfectly until today. The backup had no effect.

PS: the code was combined from several files for testing purposes, so i could make a few mistakes.

---

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <asm/termios.h>
    #include <asm/ioctls.h>
    #include <sys/signal.h>
    #include <stropts.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    bool Ports::setup_port_Sbus(Info* port)
    {
        //> check descriptor
        if (!isatty(fd)) { throw "File description is NOT a serial port!"; }
    
        //> read fole descriptor config
        struct termios2 config = { 0 };
    
        //> for interrupt
        struct sigaction saio;
        sigset_t mskvar;
        sigfillset(&mskvar);
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mskvar, NULL);
        sigdelset(&mskvar, SIGIO);
        saio.sa_handler = signal_io_handler;
        saio.sa_flags = 0;
        saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
        sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, NULL);
    
        if (ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, &config) < 0) { throw "Could not read config of FD!"; }
    
        config.c_cflag |= PARENB;  // enable parity
        config.c_cflag &= ~PARODD; // even parity
        config.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;  // enable 2 stop bits
        config.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;  // clear character size mask
        config.c_cflag |= CS8;     // 8 bit characters
        config.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;  // disable hardware flow control
        config.c_cflag |= CREAD;   // enable receiver
        config.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;  // ignore modem lines
    
        config.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;  // receive characters as they come in
        config.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;    // do not echo
        config.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;    // do not generate signals
        config.c_lflag &= ~IEXTEN;  // disable implementation-defined processing
    
        config.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);  // disable XON/XOFF flow control
        config.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;   // ignore BREAK condition
        config.c_iflag |= INPCK;    // enable parity checking
        config.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;   // ignore framing and parity errors
        config.c_iflag &= ~ISTRIP;  // do not strip off 8th bit
        config.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;   // do not translate NL to CR
        config.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;   // do not translate CR to NL
        config.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;   // do not ignore CR
    
        config.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;  // disable implementation-defined processing
        config.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;  // do not map NL to CR-NL
        config.c_oflag &= ~OCRNL;  // do not map CR to NL
        config.c_oflag &= ~(ONOCR | ONLRET);  // output CR like a normal person
        config.c_oflag &= ~OFILL;  // no fill characters
    
        // Apply baudrate
        speed_t br = 100000;
        config.c_ispeed = br;
        config.c_ospeed = br;
        config.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
        config.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    
        //> Finally, apply the configuration
        if (ioctl(fd, TCSETS2, &config) < 0) { throw "Could not set configuration of fd!"; }
        
        // Done!
        return true;
    }
        
    void port_init(){
        
        const char* _name = "/dev/ttyTHS1";
        int fd = -1;
        
        fd = open(_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
        if (fd < 0) { throw "File is not open!"; }
        else{
            fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK|O_ASYNC);
        }
        
        bool setup = setup_port_Sbus(fd);
    
        if (!setup) { throw "Could not configure port"; }
        if (fd <= 0) { throw "Connection attempt to port failed, exiting"; }
    
    }
    
    struct Sbus_data{
        bool    lost_frame;
        int failsafe;
        bool    ch17;
        bool    ch18;
        static int8_t   SBUS_NUM_CH             = 16;
        int     last_ch[SBUS_NUM_CH]    = {};
        int     ch[SBUS_NUM_CH]     = {};
    };
    
    int main(){
        
        try{
            port_init();
        }
        catch(const char* err){
            cout << "ERR: " << err << endl;
        }
        
        uint8_t byte;
        uint8_t sb_buf[SBUS_PACKET_LEN] = {};
        const int8_t SBUS_PACKET_LEN    = 25;
        const int8_t SBUS_NUM_SBUS_CH   = 16;
        const uint8_t SBUS_HEADER   = 0x0F;
        const uint8_t SBUS_FOOTER   = 0x00;
        const uint8_t SBUS_FOOTER2  = 0x04;
        const uint8_t SBUS_CH17_MASK    = 0x01;
        const uint8_t SBUS_CH18_MASK    = 0x02;
        const uint8_t SBUS_LOST_FRAME_MASK = 0x04;
        const uint8_t SBUS_FAILSAFE_MASK = 0x08;
        Sbus_data           sb_data;
        int sb_state                    = 0;
        
        do{
            count_read_symb = read(port->file_descriptor, &byte, 1);
            if(count_read_symb <= 0)
            {
                cout << "byte: " << byte << " | errno: "<< errno << endl;
                continue;
            }
    
            //> wrong start
            if(sb_state == 0 && byte != SBUS_HEADER)
            {
                continue;
            }
    
            sb_buf[sb_state++] = byte;
    
            //> index done
            if(sb_state == SBUS_PACKET_LEN)
            {
                sb_state = 0;
                if(sb_buf[24] != SBUS_FOOTER)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                sb_data.ch[0]  = ((sb_buf[1]    |sb_buf[2]<<8)                 & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[1]  = ((sb_buf[2]>>3 |sb_buf[3]<<5)                 & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[2]  = ((sb_buf[3]>>6 |sb_buf[4]<<2 |sb_buf[5]<<10)  & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[3]  = ((sb_buf[5]>>1 |sb_buf[6]<<7)                 & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[4]  = ((sb_buf[6]>>4 |sb_buf[7]<<4)                 & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[5]  = ((sb_buf[7]>>7 |sb_buf[8]<<1 |sb_buf[9]<<9)   & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[6]  = ((sb_buf[9]>>2 |sb_buf[10]<<6)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[7]  = ((sb_buf[10]>>5|sb_buf[11]<<3)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[8]  = ((sb_buf[12]   |sb_buf[13]<<8)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[9]  = ((sb_buf[13]>>3|sb_buf[14]<<5)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[10] = ((sb_buf[14]>>6|sb_buf[15]<<2|sb_buf[16]<<10) & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[11] = ((sb_buf[16]>>1|sb_buf[17]<<7)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[12] = ((sb_buf[17]>>4|sb_buf[18]<<4)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[13] = ((sb_buf[18]>>7|sb_buf[19]<<1|sb_buf[20]<<9)  & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[14] = ((sb_buf[20]>>2|sb_buf[21]<<6)                & 0x07FF);
                sb_data.ch[15] = ((sb_buf[21]>>5|sb_buf[22]<<3)                & 0x07FF);
    
                ((sb_buf[23])      & 0x0001) ? sb_data.ch[16] = 2047: sb_data.ch[16] = 0;
                ((sb_buf[23] >> 1) & 0x0001) ? sb_data.ch[17] = 2047: sb_data.ch[17] = 0;
    
                if ((sb_buf[23] >> 3) & 0x0001) { sb_data.failsafe = 1; }
                else { sb_data.failsafe = 0; }
                
                cout << "DONE!" << endl;
            }
        }
        while(count_read_symb > 0);
    }
```

- I checked ports buffer with *sudo sh 'cat < /dev/ttyTHS1'* and *Putty*, and all data was there but the read() returns zero.
- Port is in *dialout* group to which i have access, it is configured for -rw-, and no error in port initialization stage was caught.

Moreover, i have /dev/ttyUSB1 and ../ttyUSB0 with slightely different flags (no parity/ br=115200/ 1 stop bit) for TTL but they are working perfectly.

Comment: Since you configured `O_NONBLOCK`, zero is exactly what I'd expect if you tried to read the port but there was nothing there.

Comment: @MarkRansom, i know :) The real question is why it suddenly broke when other ports work fine with almost similar flags and filled the THS1 buffer.

Comment: With O_NONBLOCK return value is probably -1 with errno EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.
Return value zero indicates EOF. There are some EOF related flags in termios attributes. Maybe you should check those.

Comment: Hi @SKi, i get 0 until i fire up Putty while the code is running. Obviously, after that, i get -1.  Correct me if i am wrong, but i can't use EOF flags cause of ~ICANON so i receive all data as it comes. My port has to work without stalling and is preferably capable of sudden device disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SKi, I checked the flags.

The solution:

```
// Apply baudrate
speed_t br = 100000;
config.c_ispeed = br;
config.c_ospeed = br;
   config.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD; // !!!!!
   config.c_cflag |= BOTHER; // !!!!!
config.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
config.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

For some reason, the code used to work without those 2 lines. They are required now.